# Getting an error from my small Python sockets program. Returns "OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied"

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x, client-server

I'm following a tutorial working with Python sockets: client servers, [here][1]. I've looked into similar problems but other people are just getting spelling errors and what not. Looking forward to finding a solution!

```
import socket

import sys

from _thread import *

host = ''

port = 5555

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)


try:

    s.bind((host, port))

except socket.error as e:

    print(str(e))


s.listen(5)

def threaded_client(conn):

    conn.send(str.encode('Welcome, type your info \n'))

    while True:

        data = conn.recv(2048)

        reply = 'Server output: '+data.decode('utf-8')

        if not data:

            break

        conn.sendall(str.encode(reply))


    conn.close()


while True:

    conn, addr = s.accept()

    print('connected to: '+addr[0]+':'+str(addr[1]))        

    start_new_thread(threaded_client, (conn,))
```

The error is

```
s.listen(5)
OSError: [WinError 10022] An invalid argument was supplied
```

Thanks in advance :)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WrtebUkUssc&index=59&list=PLQVvvaa0QuDe8XSftW-RAxdo6OmaeL85M

Comment: Did you tried this code with py27? Also, which line trows an error?

Comment: @Paul Based on the question tags, it's Python3.x I guess.

Comment: @EbraHim yes, I know it. But trying to run this code under py27 is the best way to find out if there some interpreter issues. Original code was runned under py27, as it mentioned in the lesson description on youtube.

Comment: @Paul It works fine without modification in my computer. (Python v3.5)

Comment: @Paul It throws an error at "s.listen(5)"

Comment: @T.McPhee Ok, thanks. And what python version do you have on your env?

Comment: And could you please provide full stacktrace here?

Answer (score 0):

Your program works fine in my computer:

[image]